# How to place the newline character inside tool tip in react bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need to place a long paragraph inside the react bootstrap tool tip, I need to have new line in some places . I have tried \n ,br,em nothing gives me the new line.

```
export const TooltipMessages = {
 product:
   "Here we can see list of Product created and we can create a New product \r\n." +
   "We have 3 types of product Managed, Unmanaged and Source." +
   "Managed Product : Managed product is where by default all the environments are created 
    i.e Evaluation, Development," +
    "Test & Production." 
 }
```

and tool tip code

```
<Tooltip id={`tooltip-top`} className="mytooltip">
      {ToolTipMessage.product}
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this:

react [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/qm46pceb/14/)

> NOTE: It was not allowing me to add only `fiddle` so added only `css` and `html` code, full functionality is available in fiddle.

```css
.display-linebreak {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">


</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that it is getting displayed as is i.e even <br/> tag is getting printed.

Comment: or there is another way using css but for that you need to wrap the text to either `div` or `span`, is that is an option here?

Comment: @Ashishshetty I have updated the code in the fiddle, check it out.

Answer (score -1):

//react tool tip allows these props

// to make explicitly multiline tooltip comments

multiline?: boolean;

// Add 1px white border

border?: boolean;

// Popup text color

textColor?: string;

// Popup background color

backgroundColor?: string;

// Popup border color

borderColor?: string;

// Popup arrow color

arrowColor?: string;

Comment: OP is referring to react bootstrap tooltip and not custom react tooltip library. If the library you have mentioned is better than the lib mentioned by OP, please justify your answer with an elaborated answer. Thanks

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/tour for how to answer a question properly